# Chef attribute override not taking effect

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a default attribute defined:

```
/cookbook-test/attributes/default.rb
## Environemnt attributes
default['cookbook-test']['flags']['test']="dummy_flag"
```

That's overriden on a recipe (1) and is used on recipe (2)

```
/cookbook-test/recipes/default.rb
include_recipe 'cookbook-test::set-flag-based-on-file' #(1)
#...
include_recipe 'cookbook-test::other-recipe' # (2) this recipe needs the attribute
```

On the recipe that the attribute is being overridden (1), the attribute changes depending on the contents of a file:

```
/cookbook-test/recipes/set-flag-based-on-file.rb
ruby_block "Use attribute (A/B)" do
    block do
        # reads file for flag "A"/"B"
        local_flag= ::File.read('/home/user/.flag').chomp

        if local_flag== "A"
          node.set['cookbook-test']['flags']['test'] = true 
        elsif local_flag== "B"
          node.set['cookbook-test']['flags']['test'] = false
        else
          node.set['cookbook-test']['flags']['test'] = false
        end
    end
end
```

Here's how the recipe (2) is trying to use the attribute:

```
/cookbook-test/recipes/other-recipe.rb
flag= node['cookbook-test']['flags']['test']
if flag == true
  # something 
elsif flag == false
  # something
else
  Chef::Log.error("XX attribute is not SET!")
end
```

However when the cookbook runs and it gets to recipe (2) the value is still set to "dummy_flag" as it was never overridden. I tried setting the attribute with "`node.force_default`" with no success.

Having the file with a flag of "A" is not having an effect even thought the file is being read correctly...

```
var/chef/log/client.log
...
[2017-02-09T12:56:06-05:00] ERROR: XX attribute is not SET!
...
```

What am I missing, for the attribute to be overridden correctly?

Answer (score 0):

found my issue finally, the problem was that I'm trying to override the attribute inside a ruby_block which is executed later than I thought.

I removed the ruby block to force chef to run it earlier and it solved my problem.

Comment: Chef does guarantee the order, it is just not the order you thought it was. See https://coderanger.net/two-pass for an overview :)